# error while yarn update in the vue project

Tags: firebase, vue.js, yarnpkg

while building my vue project it says

```
⠴  Building for production...Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`
```

after that when i am updating my yarn in my project it gives me error.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "expected hoisted manifest for \"vue-firestore#firebase#@firebase/installations#@firebase/installations-types\"".
```

i have checked that firebase tools are already installed.
Please help.

Comment: Your `lock` file is out of date. Remove it, run `yarn` again. Problem solved.

Comment: thanks for the help.